# TCP SYN does not reach TCP server

Tags: ip, routing, tcp

I have a TCP server listening on 10.10.10.101, port 2000, running on a Windows 7 machine. Below is the corresponding output line for the command `netstat -aon`:

`TCP     10.10.10.101:2000    0.0.0.0:0                     LISTENING      2340`

I also have an FPGA which sends a TCP SYN packet every second until the server responds.

The FPGA physically connects to the directly to a network interface on the Windows 7 machine, which has been configured to have a static IP address of 10.10.10.101. The source IP address of the SYN packets is 10.10.10.100.

I can see the SYN packets being received on the network interface using WireShark, but the TCP server does not reply a SYN/ACK. My assumption is that the TCP server is not seeing the SYN packets because of routing issues.

I have manually added two routes as follows (`IF 16` refers to the interface with static IP `10.10.10.101`):

`route add 10.10.10.100 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.10.10.1 METRIC I IF 16`

`route add 10.10.10.101 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.10.10.1 METRIC I IF 16`

Have I correctly added the routes? How can I confirm that the TCP server is indeed not being forwarded the IP packets with the TCP SYN? What can I do to gain more insight into what is going wrong?

Comment: Surely if Wireshark is seeing the packets it's not a routing issue? Are you sure your TCP server is bound to that port / interface correctly? What happens if you try sending from another machine on the network?

Comment: @JonCage: My TCP server is correctly bound as confirmed by the `netstat` command (see updated question). Also, when using a different network interface (with a different IP address), the TCP server works as expected, even from another machine on the network.

Comment: it seems weird to send syn's repeatedly, and syn flooding is a common DOS vector. do you think its possible that a device in the middle is dropping the packets to prevent a DOS attack?

Comment: @FrankThomas: The FPGA is *directly* connected to the machine hosting the TCP server. There is no device in the middle. Also, WireShark is seeing all the SYNs.

Comment: Could windows firewall be dropping the packets after wireshark sees them? Seems odd that would work from another machine if you're able to successfully send the same information from another machine(?) mind you...

Comment: @JonCage: The firewall has been disabled. The same information is sent from another machine, but I think more importantly, it is sent on another network interface.

Comment: So what happens if you connect your FPGA to the 'other' interface? Your netstat output doesn't list which physical adapters it's bound to so as I said before, I'd check that...

Comment: @JonCage: I can't! The FPGA is 10Gbps, whereas the other is 1Gbps.

Comment: Try disabling the other interface then re-starting the server. My bet is it's bound to the other interface and that's the root cause of your issue.

Comment: @JonCage: Good thinking. Unfortunately, the other interface is used for remote desktop, so I can't disable that!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9493/discussion-between-jon-cage-and-randomblue)

Comment: This my be too obvious, but have you checked the destination port value of the SYN segments arriving at the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is the server has no [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) entry for the IP address the SYN is coming from, so it has no way to put a reply packet on the Ethernet wire because it doesn't know what Ethernet hardware address to send the reply to.

Comment: You got it right, congratulations! Adding a new entry in the ARP table fixed it! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've said in your post, my money would be that the server you're running is bound to the wrong interface.

If you have the option, try disabling the interface you've tested that works from other machines and then re-start your server software.

If you can't disable or disconnect the other interface because you're using that to remote desktop into the server machine, how about plugging the FPGA into that interface and your remote desktop connection into the interface the FPGA is currently connected to?

If you're able to modify the server software I'd suggest checking what interface(s) it's being bound to - I've had issues along those lines before when using windows network bindings (sending / receiving UDP broadcasts on the wrong interface)..